# "Cannot access a closed Stream" when using Bitmap

Tags: c#, smartinspect

My code works perfectly in little demo app, however, when I run it in the big production system it throws the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Length()
   at Gurock.SmartInspect.LogEntry.get_Size()
   at Gurock.SmartInspect.SchedulerCommand.get_Size()
   at Gurock.SmartInspect.SchedulerQueue.Remove(SchedulerQueueItem item)
   at Gurock.SmartInspect.SchedulerQueue.Dequeue()
   at Gurock.SmartInspect.Scheduler.Dequeue()
   at Gurock.SmartInspect.Scheduler.Run()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext,
     ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext,
     ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Here is the C# code that leads to the error:

```
// This grabs a bitmap from Mathematica. It works 95% of the time.
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Globals.State.Mathematica.EvaluateToImage(cmdGraph, 0, 0));

// Log to SmartInspect.
SiAuto.Main.LogBitmap("test", bitmap); // Errors disappear if this line is removed.
```

Comment: Use the vendor's support forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue.

If SmartInspect v3.3.2.48 is run in asynchronous mode, it will sometimes throw this error if dealing with bitmaps. The solution is to remove all of the "async" tags in the connection string.

My previous value for `SiAuto.Si.Connections` was:

```
pipe(reconnect="true", reconnect.interval="30", backlog.enabled="true", backlog.flushon="debug", backlog.keepopen="true", async.enabled="true")
```

If I change it to this, it works:

```
pipe(reconnect="true", reconnect.interval="30", backlog.enabled="true", backlog.flushon="debug", backlog.keepopen="true")
```

As an aside, SmartInspect is excellent, and I have no complaints. This is the first issue I've ever discovered with it in 2 years, and as I am using a version that's a year old this issue was probably fixed in the latest release anyway.